# How does the first moment affect convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I have the following problem on my Statistics Problem Set:

[image]

I was able to use the multivariate Delta Method and solve items a) and b). However, I am struggling with items c) and d). Let me present my intuitions:

C) If $\mu_{X} = 0$, then the expected value of the ration of these two sample means is truly $\mu_{X}/\mu_{Y} = 0$ by the Law of Iterated Expectations. However, if this is not the case, Jensen's inequality kicks in and this won't hold anymore. However, I cannot go any further.

D) I have the impression that nothing can be said in this case with little information. I think that this thing won't converge to anything.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In d you can't even really be sure that the problem makes sense, because the $Y_i$ could even be identically zero. Or is there an assumption that $\sigma_{XX},\sigma_{YY}>0$?

Comment: @Ian very good point, I hadn't thought about this. Thanks!

Comment: As for c, you can again get some intuition in the relatively trivial case when the $X_i$ are identically equal to $\mu_X$. Now in case b the random variable is just zero but in case a there are fluctuations due to variation in $\overline{Y}_n$ (which presumably do not wash out under $\sqrt{n}$ scaling), unless $\mu_X=0$ in which case both of them are just zero. In this latter case you need to be more careful.